# How to replace special characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

How to replace the special characters like ")" in the string "Richardson & Cruddas (R & C), Jhon (J)" in javascript

Comment: you have to escape the ) like so `/\)/g`

Comment: `str.replace(/)/g,"%29")` you have some hanging code here and you have one ) dangling. Also do a bit more research on structuring you regex using a site like rexegr.com

Answer (score 1):

The `)` character in regular expressions is a special character. You'll have to escape it:

```
str = str.replace(/\)/g,"%29")
```